# Pre Loading the embedded sound before playing

Tags: actionscript-3

```
package{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
public class MySoundContainer extends MovieClip {
 var _mySound:MySound = new MySound();  // my custom sound imported in library 

 public function _OnButtonClick(e:MouseEvent) : void {
   _mySound.play();  // first call shows delay in play
 } 
}
}
```

When the button is clicked **first time**, I see a noticeable delay in playing the sound.

Is it possible to preload the sound effect before hand for the embedded files?

Answer (score 1):

May be calling `play` and mute the sound (with volume = 0) when the app start and return volume back later in `_OnButtonClick` will help you.

But it's strange, embed sounds don't need in preloading, they are already loaded with the swf file. May be it's bufferization or volume fade (increasing volume from 0 to 1 for 1-2 sec) in the beginning of mp3 file. Does this delay occur only at first click?

Comment: Yeah, the delay is happening only at first click. I was also thinking of the same solution that you have suggested. Was wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: I'm afraid there isn't better variants. Embedding mp3 to the swf is the fastest way to play the sound. May be there is some overhead in flash player when calling sound first time (some decoding or reading file into memory for example) so I guess if you come around this issue the best way is call _play_ in advance.

Comment: I found that the problem was with previewing the game in flash. when I ran the compiled swf, it worked fine. I have added a link as well which helped me found the reason in my answer

Answer (score 0):

[Latency in playing short sounds in flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227674/latency-in-playing-short-sounds-in-flash-9-actionscript-3) helped me immensely to understand various reasons for latency in sound play.

I found (from the above link) that the problem was happening only while previewing within flash. It works perfectly when running the compiled swf.

In case somebody runs into a issue like I did, they should try to do File->Publish and run the .html file.